# Wix Bootstraper DetectMsiFeature method is not called

Tags: .net, bootstrapper

I have written a custom bootstrapper application using wix BA.

The application contains 2 packages and each of these these packages contains 2 features.

I have read the link https://www.wrightfully.com/part-4-of-writing-your-own-net-based-installer-with-wix-handling-current-and-future-state/ and understood that the event DetectMsiFeature is used to detect which are the features installed from given package.

However the DetectMSIPackage method itself is not called.

How can we call the DetectMsiFeature method of Wix BootStrapper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check that you have performed following 3 steps, and you should be able to execute `DetectMSIPackage` method.

1: You have wired up the even handler i.e. `this.model.BootstrapperApplication.DetectMsiFeature += BootstrapperApplication_DetectMsiFeature;`

2: You have called the Detect method of engine `this.model.BootstrapperApplication.Engine.Detect();`

3: You have setup `EnableFeatureSelection="yes"` property in MSIPackage node of your Bundle.wxs